# Object array - null pointer exception

Tags: java, oop, nullpointerexception

I need a method returning array of object. Below is my code but I'm getting null pointer exception and don't know why.

```
    public Place[] getPlaces() 
    {
        Place result[] = null ;
        int counter = 0;

        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = this.db.prepareStatement("select * from places");

            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()) {
                Place p = new Place();
                p.setPlaceID(rs.getInt("placeID"));
                p.setPlaceName(rs.getString("placeName"));

                result[counter] = p;
                counter++;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

On line `result[counter] = p;` eclipse says :

Multiple markers at this line
- Null pointer access: The variable result can only be null at this location

So, I added `@SuppressWarnings("null")` before my method. But, when method is called it throws null pointer exception. Before the line I'm having trouble, tried to print place name stored in db and it worked. So, this is not a database issue as error output says:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at PlaceMod.getPlaces(PlaceMod.java:29)
    at PlaceCont.list(PlaceCont.java:15)
    at Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: You initialize `result` to `null`, but then never modify it to point at an actual array.

Comment: Only use `@SuppressWarnings("null")` when you are sure you know what you do.

Comment: `@SuppressWarnings("null")` is almost never the correct way to solve warnings. You should be trying to figure out what the warning is telling you. In this case it's saying like @OliCharlesworth is saying that `result` will be `null` at that point.

Comment: Does it have to be an ArrayList? I thought at least one value is assigned to result[] since database can't be empty - counter starts with zero and result[0] should be initialized . In php this would work. Can you kindly explain what I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You created a null array. Use an `ArrayList` (since you don't know the size of the resultset):

```
 List<Place> result = new ArrayList<>();

 while(rs.next()) {
   ...
   result.add(p);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You never assigned an array to `result` therefore it is still `null` when you try `result[counter] = p;`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize your array. You have to put something like `result = new Place[size]` before you use this array (size is the length of your array). You should consider using `ArrayList` here.